# Inconsistent order of vertices/faces in obj files animation

Tags: animation, vertices, faces, obj

I'm creating old-school renderer, where I'm trying to interpolate between `obj` file frames.
After exporting skeletal animation to multiple `obj` files I see that order of vertices/faces is not exactly the same in every `obj` frame file.

**Visual representation of 2 `obj` keyframes with 3 bones animated:**
[image]

What can I do in Blender to fix this issue?
Or maybe there is better way to do it?

I already tried to:

- Check `Keep vertex order` during export
- Add `Triangulate` modifier in object modifiers (to keep consistent triangulation)
- Experimenting with `Sort elements`

but with no success..

`blend` and `obj`s [files attached.](https://mega.nz/file/SpMkQLIb#N1STkJfmBBbBXh74nakJ30jaPW_RURYbYqKavh4Np3g)

Thanks.